# Difference between first and last row in grouping

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, grouping

I have this table taken from very complex query, that is, it's not possible to join on itself. 
Rows are ordered by time desc.

```
type, value, time
+---+----+
| 2 |  2 |
| 2 |  7 |
| 3 | 20 |
| 3 | 16 |
+---+----+
```

I need to calculate the difference between first and last value per one type grouping, in the given example this will give me

```
+---+----+
| 2 | -5 |
| 3 | 4  |
+---+----+
```

Is it feasible?

Comment: would each type have 2 rows of data only?

Comment: yes, it's a result of subquery which returns only 2 last values per each type

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One method uses window functions.  Something like this works:

```
select distinct type,
       (first_value(value) over (partition by type order by time asc) -
        first_value(value) over (partition by type order by time desc)
       ) as diff        
from t;
```

Unfortunately, Postgres doesn't have a `first_value()` aggregation function.

You could also do this using `array_agg()`:

```
select distinct type,
       ((array_agg(value order by time asc))[1] -
        (array_agg(value order by time desc))[1]
       ) as diff        
from t
group by type;
```

Comment: Is it possible without using postgresql specific functions, just using window functions?

Comment: `first_value()` is a standard analytic function.